# EAR not Deploying (org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException)

Tags: jpa, ejb-3.0, eclipselink

I'm using Websphere, JSF 1.2, JPA (Eclipselink)
On my project I have the following structure:

```
-APHP0000_EJB
    .APHP0000FacadeEJB.java
    .Controllers (Managers)
    .persistence.xml
-APHP0000_EJBClient 
    .APHP0000FacadeEJBLocal.java
    .APHP0000FacadeEJBRemote.java
    .Entyties
    .TO
-APHP0000_EJBEAR
-APHP0000_Web (depends on APHP0000_EJBClient )
    .jsp
    .ManageBeans
-APHP0000_WebEAR 

-->persistence.xml 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="APHP0000_EJB" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:comp/env/ds_aphp_web</jta-data-source>

    <jar-file>APHP0000_EJBClient.jar</jar-file>

    <class>su.aphpweb.jpa.entities.UnidadeProdutiva</class>
    <class>su.aphpweb.jpa.entities.TipoParadaN4</class>
    ...
    <class>su.aphpweb.jpa.entities.MaquinaProdutiva</class>

    <properties>
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.level" value="FINE" />
        <property name="eclipselink.target-server"      value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.server.was.WebSphere_7_Platform" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jtaDataSource" value="jdbc/ds_aphp_web" />
                <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false" />
        <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true" />
</properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

When I Start my container, my APHP0000_EJBEAR is deployed, but my APHP0000_WebEAR  is not. and get the following exception. Please, I'm stuck on this thing since last week.

```
[19/12/12 13:33:49:898 BRST] 00000006 JPAPUnitInfo  E   CWWJP0015E: Ocorreu um erro no provedor de persistência org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider quando ele tentou criar factory de gerenciador de entidade do contêiner para a unidade de persistência APHP0000_EJB. Ocorreu o seguinte erro: Exception [EclipseLink-28018] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.EntityManagerSetupException
Exception Description: Predeployment of PersistenceUnit [APHP0000_EJB] failed.
Internal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Equipe\APHP\APHP0000_EJB\ejbModule\APHP0000_EJBClient.jar (O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado.)
[19/12/12 13:33:49:898 BRST] 00000006 JPAPUnitInfo  E   CWWJP0009E: O servidor não pode criar um depósito de informações EntityManagerFactory para a unidade persistente APHP0000_EJB do provedor org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider no módulo file:/D:/Equipe/APHP/APHP0000_EJB/ejbModule/.
[19/12/12 13:33:49:914 BRST] 00000006 EJBContainerI I   WSVR0037I: Iniciando o jar do EJB: APHP0000_EJB.jar
[19/12/12 13:33:49:914 BRST] 00000006 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: O servidor está ligando a interface su.aphpweb.jpa.entities.controller.ResponsParadaUnidManagerRemote do enterprise bean ResponsParadaUnidManager no módulo APHP0000_EJB.jar do aplicativo APHP0000_WebEAR.  O local de ligação é: ejb/APHP0000_WebEAR/APHP0000_EJB.jar/ResponsParadaUnidManager#su.aphpweb.jpa.entities.controller.ResponsParadaUnidManagerRemote
[19/12/12 13:33:49:914 BRST] 00000006 EJBContainerI I   CNTR0167I: O servidor está ligando a interface su.aphpweb.jpa.entities.controller.UnidadeMotivoTipoManagerRemote do enterprise bean UnidadeMotivoTipoManager no módulo APHP0000_EJB.jar do aplicativo APHP0000_WebEAR.  O local de ligação é: ejb/APHP0000_WebEAR/APHP0000_EJB.jar/UnidadeMotivoTipoManager#su.aphpweb.jpa.entities.controller.UnidadeMotivoTipoManagerRemote
[19/12/12 13:33:49:914 BRST] 00000006 ComponentData E   CWMDF0015E: O carregador de classes não pode carregar a interface su.aphpweb.negocio.ejb.APHP0000FacadeEJBRemote no arquivo su.aphpweb.negocio.ejb.APHP0000FacadeEJB Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB). 
[19/12/12 13:33:49:914 BRST] 00000006 EJBContainerI E   WSVR0040E: Falha no addEjbModule para APHP0000_EJB.jar [class com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedEJBModuleImpl]
com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: CWMDF0015E: O carregador de classes não pode carregar a interface su.aphpweb.negocio.ejb.APHP0000FacadeEJBRemote no arquivo su.aphpweb.negocio.ejb.APHP0000FacadeEJB Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB). 
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ComponentDataObject.setInterfacesFromImplements(ComponentDataObject.java:783)
    at com.ibm.ws.metadata.ComponentDataObject.finishCDO(ComponentDataObject.java:424)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.startModule(EJBContainerImpl.java:2609)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.EJBContainerImpl.start(EJBContainerImpl.java:3827)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1120)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1313)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:619)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:938)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:723)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$1.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1264)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4476)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4654)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1269)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2041)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:437)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:380)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:651)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:613)
    at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1175)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:243)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1086)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:967)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1320)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1213)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl._startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1284)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1180)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.application.AppManagementImpl.startApplication(AppManagementImpl.java:1140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:243)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1086)
    at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:967)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:773)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1320)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1213)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi.RMIConnectorService.invoke(RMIConnectorService.java:282)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie.invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:395)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.rmi._RMIConnectorService_Tie._invoke(_RMIConnectorService_Tie.java:160)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatchInvokeHandler(ServerDelegate.java:622)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ServerDelegate.dispatch(ServerDelegate.java:475)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:513)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.process(ORB.java:1574)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.respondTo(Connection.java:2841)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.Connection.doWork(Connection.java:2714)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.WorkUnitImpl.doWork(WorkUnitImpl.java:63)
    at com.ibm.ejs.oa.pool.PooledThread.run(ThreadPool.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to indicate that it can't find the jar file, APHP0000_EJBClient.jar. Is the jar in the ear?  It needs to be.

You could try removing the  tag, and just list the entity classes (as long as there are on the classpath they will be found).

Answer (score 0):

For EJB Exception :CWMDF0015E 
 It is necessary to click in the paramètrage of publication for WebSphere Application Server of Eclipse IDE "to execute the server and the resources on the server"

and run a server